# Lifecycle of blocks in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

```
MyBlock getBlocks()
{    
    MyBlock myBlock = ^{
        NSLog(@"Hello World!");
    };

    return myBlock;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    MyBlock myBlock = getBlocks();

    myBlock();

    [pool drain];

    return 0;
}
```

Why does this snippet of code work? myBlock should be destroyed.

By the way, this snippet also works:

```
NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];

NSLog(@"%ld", [obj retainCount]);

MyBlock myBlock = ^{
    NSLog(@"Hello World!");
    NSLog(@"%ld", [obj retainCount]);
};

[obj release];
```

but [obj retainCount] in block prints 1 instead 2, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blocks can be allocated on the stack for performance reasons and only migrate away to the heap when you copy them. If your block doesn't capture any values, the compiler can also turn it into a global block whose memory exists in some fixed static memory location.

Since your `getBlocks` block doesn't capture anything, it is a global block and its memory can't be disposed. It doesn't have reference counting semantics and retain/release won't do anything. Its reference will always be valid and you'll always be able to call it.

If the block in `getBlocks` *did* capture some values, it would be a local stack-allocated block, and the method would be returning a reference to that stack memory, which is of course very dangerous. The code may even still work in this case and you'd be able to call it even though it is sitting in unowned stack memory (as long as that memory hasn't been trashed by somebody else by the time you call the block).

I believe your second example is also demonstrating the side effects of a stack-allocated block. The objects captured by a stack-allocated block will only be retained when the block is actually copied to the heap for the first time. This doesn't happen in your code so `obj` isn't retained by the block.

This does mean that after calling `[obj release]` in your example, the block is now capturing a dangling pointer. Using ARC will fix all these messy details for you.

See [How blocks are implemented (and the consequences)](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/how-blocks-are-implemented-and.html) (Cocoa With Love) for more details.

Edit: Also, obligatory link to [when to use `retainCount`](http://whentouseretaincount.com/)

Comment: +1, I agree with the analysis. The first snippet is working by coincidence and it shouldn't be relied upon. About the `retainCount`, paragraph `NSMallocBlock never actually copies` of the linked article explains why: it is never increased for as it is implemented. Also it's worth mentioning: http://whentouseretaincount.com/ :P

Comment: It's not said that the block is on the stack, it may be global as well.

Comment: The block in the first example will be definitely global.

Comment: @RamyAlzuhouri blocks are allocated on the stack unless explicitly copied (or implicitly by ARC in some cases). By the way I misread the retain count question. I posted my own answer to clarify it better

Comment: Thanks, I'm guessing that ARC automatically copies block, when I return it from function?

Comment: I've made this community wiki, others can fix the details about global blocks because I don't have time atm.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Also global blocks exist, and this is the case, try to print the block class.

Comment: @VladimirS Yes, ARC will copy it for you when you return it.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does this snippet of code work?

The first snipped is working because the block implementation has no reference to the surrounding scope, and it's therefore configured by clang as a ***global*** block. This causes the block not to be on the stack as it would normally be.

> myBlock should be destroyed.

Stack frames (and their local variable) don't get *destroyed*. Their memory is made available for further allocation. Anyway, due to the simplicity of your example, you're getting a global block which doesn't live on the stack frame.

If you were making any reference to the surrounding scope you would have had a stack-based block and `myBlock` would have been a dangling pointer to an on-owned memory location, likely leading to a crash.

> `[obj retainCount]` in block prints 1 instead 2, why?

Sounds reasonable.

You are allocating an object (retain count: 1), the block is retaining it (retain count: 2), you are releasing it (retain count: 1), the block is eventually executed (retain count still 1).

As a general note, anyway, don't rely upon `retainCount` when reasoning about memory. The memory management process has a lot going on under the hood, and you cannot definitely say anything only by looking at the value of `retainCount`, due to internal details of the implementation that you cannot possibly take into account. More on the subject here: http://whentouseretaincount.com/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about retainCount

Comment: The first code snippet doesn't work by coincidence. Try to push on the stack a variable as big as enough to overwrite the memory where the supposed stack block is allocated, the code will still work. Because the block is global, not on the stack.